# MySQL Select WHERE IN recordset

Tags: mysql, arrays, nested, where-clause, recordset

I'll try to explain my problem. I have two tables. In the first one each record is identified by a unique INT code (counter). In the second the code from the first table is one of the fields (and may be repeated in various records).

I want to make a `SELECT CODE` in the second table, based on `WHERE` parameters, knowing I will get as result a recordset with possibly repeated `CODES`, and use this recordset for another `SELECT` in the first table, `WHERE CODE IN` the above recordset (from the second table).

Is this possible ?? And if yes, how to do this ?

Usually, if I use the `WHERE IN` clause, the array can contain repeated values like `WHERE` Code `IN` "3,4,5,6,3,4,2" ... right ? The difference here is that I want to use a previously Selected recordset in place of the array.

Comment: learn about Joins.http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/; also understand cardinality.  What you have is a one to many relationship A--> where A.Code = B.A_CODE and B.A_Code can be repeated (thus is the nature of a foreign key) It sounds like you only want to display values from the A. Table  You can do this using an exists and a coorlated subquery or you can use an outer join and a group by or distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is this possible ??** Sure is.

**And if yes, how to do this ?**  Like most questions answers depends. There's more than one way to skin this cat; and depending on data (volume of records), and indexes answers can vary.

You can use a distinct or group by to limit the table A records because the join from A--> b is a 1--> many thus we need to distinct or group by the values from A as they would be repeated.  But if you need values from B as well, this is the way to do it.

```
Select A.Code, max(count B.A_CODE) countOfBRecords
from B
LEFT JOIN A
 on A.Code = B.A_Code
WHERE B.Paramater = 'value'
 and B.Paramater2 = 'Value2'
group by A.Code)
```

Or using your approach (works if you ONLY need values/columns from table A.)

```
Select A.Code 
from A
Where code in (Select B.A_CODE
               From B WHERE B.Paramater = 'value'
                and B.Paramater2 = 'Value2')
```

But these can be slow depending on data/indexes.

You don't need the distinct on the inner query as A.Code only exists once and thus wouldn't be repeated. It's the JOIN which would cause the records to repeat not the where clause.

-Correlated Subquery  will return a single A.Code works if you ONLY need values from table A.

```
Select A.Code
From A
Where exists (Select 1 
              from B 
              where b.paramter = value ... 
                AND A.Code = B.A_CODE)
```

Since there's no join no A.records would be repeated. On larger data sets this generally performs better .

This last approach works because it Correlates the outer table with sub select  Note this can only go 1 level in a relationship.  If you had multiple levels deep trying to join this way, it woudln't work.

Comment: First of all ... thank you very very much !! The last solution seem the best for my case, according to what you described (I just need values from field in A table and will go just one level deep in nesting). I just have a question ... in the subquery you wrote SELECT 1 FROM B ... what does that "1" mean/represent ?

Comment: another sub question ... can i write something like : select a.code from a where exists (select 1 from B where ....) AND exists (select 1 from C where ....) ???

Comment: ... just for you to have an idea, these tables have a few tens of thousands records average size.

Comment: the 1 is because the select has to return a value but we don't care what that value is.  All we care is that the A.Code and B.A_Code match.    With regards to your 2nd question yes you can have multiple exists using and/or notation.  I would ensure the columns you're joining on are indexed in each table; likely will be if they are truly Foreign keys.

Comment: Already in production and working PERFECTLY (one query has 2 exists and one NOT exists) !! ... thanks a lot xQbert